# Google Sheets, simple adding sequence

Tags: google-sheets

As shown below, I have week one starting on July 18, and I want to then fill in every week from then on, but I don't want to have to keep manually typing and filling after week three.
I know there must be a simple formula to fill in a number and then '+1' for the row below it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are needing to manually type... You should only need the first two rows of the third column, then you can autofill the rest.

The second row here shows the formula of the cells below it

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: Sorry, I am referencing column 1.  Column 3 autofills itself, but I would like for column 1 to keep filling each week for the format it is in.

Comment: And that is what the formula I have shown does. `WEEKNUM(date)` will return the week number, then I subtracted 29 to get it starting at 1